# Problema no run do Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Eu estava tentando arrumar um problema no meu Java, no Run. Quando fui tentar executar o Run novamente (sendo que não tinha mudado nada ainda, só tinha aberto as configurações do Run) deu o seguinte problema:

[image: Imagem do Erro]

Comment: É só esse o erro, não nenhuma outra mensagem? um projeto novo ou diferente vc consegue executar?

Comment: Nennhuma outra mensagem, e em um projeto novo ou diferente mesma coisa.

Comment: Tenta clicar no Run com a pasta do projeto selecionada ou clicar com o direito na pasta do projeto e ir em Run As... -> Java Aplication

Comment: Descompactar outro Eclipse e configurá-lo seria muito trabalhoso? Talvez seja mais fácil do que tentar arrumar esse aí...

Comment: Já tentei usar esse, e a dica do G Zulian funcionou, vlw